# Using Office 365 Graph API, how to search in sent mails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We need to search mails in `Sent Mail` folder. Currently it is searching in `Inbox` alone. What is the call we need to use for searching mail in all folder or the `Sent Mail` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph API gives support to the outlook api. If you are interested in Graph API then try this.

```
GET /me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages?$select=sender,subject
```

You can use well-known folder names such as Inbox, Drafts, SentItems, or DeletedItems to identify certain mail folders that exist by default for all users.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/{folder_id}/messages

The folder ID, or the Inbox, Drafts, SentItems, or DeletedItems well-known folder name, if you're getting messages from a specific folder. Specifying AllItems would return all messages from the entire mailbox.

Comment: That is Outlook api. Is it possible in Graph api? We moved entire codebase from Outlook api to Graph on recommendation